# Is it common to have wire leading to dishwasher without an intermediary plug?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, dishwasher

I'm thinking of swapping my dishwasher for storage due to small kitchen size and the fact that we never use it. I'd do so in a way that if I (or a buyer when I go to sell) could easily put one back in.

I went to look under it to consider what all would need to be done, and I noticed that the electrical connection was just a 3-wire connection poking out between the drywall and the floor, hardwired onto screws on the dishwasher. No plug was used. Is this the standard setup in the US?

Comment: What make/model is your dishwasher?

Answer (score 3):

> a 3-wire connection **poking out between the drywall and the floor**,
>   hardwired onto screws on the dishwasher.

The poking out from a gap part is not right - there should be a junction box and cord stain relief. Likewise, there should be a cover for the connection on the dishwasher itself, not exposed live electrical screws. Other than those, it's not uncommon.

Comment: Good to know. With this in mind, I've added/edited my question if you want to take a stab at it. Thank you!

Comment: @Sidney It would actually be better to take your second question, and ask it as a separate question, with a link to this one for context.